# Filtering data using a where clause to get results on today's date

Tags: sql, oracle, datefilter

I am trying to create a query filtering a date field for results on today's date using a where clause. I have tried many different suggestions but I just can't seem to get the query to work. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Please do give some example ? Also please do specify what type of data is your column you are using in where clause ? And of course please do show us your query that you describe : "but I just can't seem to get the query to work".

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, a simple option is

```
where trunc(date_column) = trunc(sysdate)
```

It can have some variations depending on what you really have.

For example: if there's an index on `date_column` and table is *large* (has many rows), such an approach will make that index "unusable" so you'd want to avoid that and use e.g.

```
where date_column >= trunc(sysdate)
  and date_column <  trunc(sysdate + 1)
```